# R convert column names into rows

Tags: r, tidyr

This is my data frame:

```
    structure(list(alpha = c(0.1, 0.5), w = c(-0.00274974306224061, 
-0.000196166328114611), w_sd = c(0.0551810481758757, 0.0578592391790738
), x = c(33.1362337290378, 39.5506108643837), x_sd = c(3.1665690944253, 
3.326430870477), y = c(-5.31333502177223e-05, 0.000993858599634651
), y_sd = c(0.00281795557473473, 0.00521256102447982), z = c(7.36644492272648, 
0.948467218571388), z_sd = c(3.51648260725539, 3.66294238952056
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
alpha | stock | mean | sd
0.1   |   x   
0.5   |   x
0.1   |   y
0.5   |   y
0.1   |   z
0.5   |   z
0.1   |   z
0.5   |   z
```

Where the mean and sd columns contain the values from `w`, `x`, etc and `w_sd`, `x_sd`, etc, respectively.

EDIT: Note that "alpha" is the input into a function through the argument `parameter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

- I first had to make a slight modification to your column names which where merely a single letter as we needed them for `mean` values and they would then resemble your other columns
- I then created new column names, one `stock` to store all the prefix letters and the other two specified by `.value` argument so that part of the name `sd` or `mean` will be defined as the variable containing the cell values

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~ gsub("([[:alpha:]])", "\\1_mean", .), !contains("sd") & !c(1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(!alpha, names_to = c("stock", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "([[:alpha:]])_(.*)")

# A tibble: 8 x 4
  alpha stock       mean      sd
  <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.1 w     -0.00275   0.0552 
2   0.1 x     33.1       3.17   
3   0.1 y     -0.0000531 0.00282
4   0.1 z      7.37      3.52   
5   0.5 w     -0.000196  0.0579 
6   0.5 x     39.6       3.33   
7   0.5 y      0.000994  0.00521
8   0.5 z      0.948     3.66
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But what if "alpha" is the argument of a function? The argument being called ``parameter``. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oh you are referring to that `alpha` I used in `gsub` as regex? That has nothing to do with your `alpha` variable, it is just an odd coincidence. It is a regular expression matching only letters as our original variables starts with `w`, `x` etc. In any case where we would like to capture first part of our column names before `_`  which is a single letter that remains unchanged.

Comment: I excluded first column `alpha` from any data manipulation, thsese `alpha`s in the code are just regular expressions.

Comment: Got it. Whereas ``!alpha`` is the real alpha. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Yes exactly. You're welcome. Please download `stringr` cheatsheet from this link and you will find out more about them. It's very helpful:
https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Comment: Oe even `Regular Expressions`  cheatsheet will be of great help.